# Javascript: send array through post

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, post

I am making a site that links an unlimited number of physical addresses to one account.  When an address is added, the script checks the fields and puts the contents of each field into the corresponding array.  It also counts the number of times this happens to make it easier to loop through my arrays on the server and make an insert statement for the database.  Is there a way to send these arrays back to the server through post, and if so, how do I make them readable to PHP?

EDIT: Rafe Kettler's comment below helps a lot.  It's exactly what I need, and makes my job a ton easier.  Thanks for the help.  The "Answer" I selected reflects the type of coding I will need to do and has shown me that 1) it's possible and 2) it's not all that difficult.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery.post
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Sample:
js:

```
function post_2_server(){
    $.post("/test.php", { temp: ["test1","test2"], temp2: "test" },
       function(json) {
         $.each(json.items, function(key, value) { 
           alert(key + ': ' + value); 
         });
    });
}
```

php:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST)){
       echo json_encode(array('items'=>array(1,2,3,4)))
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try [serializing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)  and [unserializing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the array

Comment: The OP is needing a JS-related way. You can serialize in JS, but JSON is simpler to use.

Comment: He has to choose, which way he like to use. both possible to do it.

Comment: You're still only providing the server-side method. Read the question; the OP wants a way for JS to *send* serialized data to the server from the browser.